# problemas haciendo un select y update en la misma sentencia al hacer un insert

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando realizar que cuando inserto un local comercial nuevo, hacer un select de ese id que inserto nuevo.

```
$idpersona = $_SESSION['persona_id'];
                $consult = '';
                $consulta = "SELECT idlocales from personas where id=".$idpersona;
                $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);

                if($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                    $consult = $row['idlocales'];
                }
                if($consult == '') {
                    $consult = $id;
                    $_SESSION['idlocales'] = $id;

                } else {
                    $consult .= ','.$id;
                    $_SESSION['idlocales'] .= ','.$id;
                }
```

> ```
> $consultat = "UPDATE personas set idlocales = '".$consult."' where id=".$persona;
> ```

haciendo un update a la tabla de las personas donde tiene un campo donde se guardan los idlocales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta usar el insert_id(), esta función devuelve el ID generado por una consulta en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT. Si la última consulta no fue una sentencia INSERT o UPDATE o si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, está función devolverá null.

En este link puedes ver los ejemplos: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: el detalle es que solo me esta ejecutando el select y no el update

Comment: Dice que esta intentando  insertar un local comercial nuevo, cuando haga ese insert, con la funcion isert_id() puede obtener el id del insert realizado anteriormente, ese id lo guarda en una variable $ultimo_id = last_id();  que después lo puede utilizar en consulta para hacer un select o un update.   SELECT * FROM personas WHERE idlocales = $ultimo_id;

Comment: lo que me esta haciendo solamente es un update temporal por los _Session, una vez que refresco el id del local deja de visualizarse y en la tabla nunca se le asigno el id al usuario